# Draw Image Not Keeping Dimensions Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm creating something in Javascript/jQuery that will take an image, and reconstruct it as a multidimensional array.  Due to the user being enabled to upload their own image, I need to get the image dimensions on the fly, and use them to scale the canvas accordingly, and draw the image.

Only issue is, the process of scaling the canvas, and then drawing to it is apparently throwing me off. What is happening now is that the canvas is scaling to the image size correctly, but what gets drawn to the canvas has its dimensions all whacked up.

Hopefully someone can give me some insight!

HTML

```
<div class="canvas">
  <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</div>
<div class="options">
  <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
</div>
<div id="status">
  <h1>Image to Multidimensional Array</h1>
  <p>What this does it pretty much self explanatory, it turns any uploaded image into a multidimensional array.
    <br/>The array is structured so that for every array inside the main array is a Y coord. Every bit of data inside of that Y array is an X coord.</p>
  <h2>Output</h2>
  <br>
  <p>
    <span id="statusout" onClick="this.select();"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function loadCanvas(dataURL, width, height) {
  $('#myCanvas').css({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // load image from data url
  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    var datalocation;
    var datalocationhex;
    var coord;
    for (var y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
      $('#statusout').append("[");
      for (var x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
        datalocation = context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        datalocationhex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(datalocation[0], datalocation[1], datalocation[2])).slice(-6);
        coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
        if (x == 0) {
          $('#statusout').append("'" + datalocationhex + "'");
        } else {
          $('#statusout').append(",'" + datalocationhex + "'");
        }
      }
      if (y == canvas.height) {
        $('#statusout').append("]<br>");
      } else {
        $('#statusout').append("],<br>");
      }
    }
  };

  function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    if (r > 255 || g > 255 || b > 255)
      throw "Invalid color component";
    return ((r << 16) | (g << 8) | b).toString(16);
  }

  imageObj.src = dataURL;
}

function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = e.target.result;
      if (img.complete) { // was cached
        var width = img.width;
        var height = img.height;
        loadCanvas(e.target.result, width, height);
      } else { // wait for decoding
        img.onload = function() {
          var width = img.width;
          var height = img.height;
          loadCanvas(e.target.result, width, height);
        }
      }
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

So yeah, that's what I've got.
Thanks a lot for any help in advance!

**EDIT**
Here's a [link to the project on CodePen](http://codepen.io/darrylhuffman/pen/LVEbey) to get a better view of things.

**EDIT v2**  It looks like the canvas is a little confused.   The multidimensional array is getting spit out fine - well, kind of.  It will go spits out the correct code for the image, and then a bunch of extra blank spots.   So something is still going wrong with the canvas draw.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the Canvas element will only listen to width and height attributes, and not CSS rules when it comes to drawing the canvas.

This is what I changed:

```
  $('#myCanvas').css({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
```

Turned into this:

```
  $('#myCanvas').attr({
    width: width,
    height: height
  });
```